# Как сделать выборку из базы за эту неделю?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Доброго времени суток, кодеры =)

Нужно сделать выборку из базы данных по дате за эту неделю т.е. за 3-9 Сентября.

Выборку по дате я делаю так:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date like '%$datesearch%'")
```

Comment: [Operator between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, не желательно называть поле **date**. Пусть это будет **my_time**. А дальше, в общем-то всё просто:

```
SELECT *
    FROM `tbl_name`
WHERE 
    `my_time` > DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL( DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE() ) -1 ) DAY )
AND 
    `my_time` < DATE_ADD( CURDATE() , INTERVAL( 9 - DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE() ) ) DAY )
```

В итоге, [смотрим, какая картина получается](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0e97/2)

Comment: Так работает, только почему то неделя начинается с воскресенья?

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from `table` where `date` >= '2012-09-03' and `date` <= '2012-09-09'
```

Подробност зависят от типа поля `date`.

Comment: Спасибо, а как мне высчитать эту неделю программно чтобы было?

Comment: [Функции даты и времени](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще оператор `between` (между):

```
select * from `table` where `date` between '2012-09-03' and '2012-09-09'
```